# Material React Table - Grouping - How to change color of top grouping bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table built in React using material-react-table and I have the table auto grouping by "Name" (See code below)

Material-react-table gives a nice display that shows which item is grouped by showing the user a light blue bar across the top. I wanted to change this light blue color to something else, how can I do it?

This is the current pixel color HEX that is displaying: #E5F6FD (rgb(229, 246, 253))

```
<MaterialReactTable
            columns={dataColumns}
            data={data}
            enableGrouping
            enableColumnResizing
            initialState={{
              density: "compact",
              expanded: true, //expand all groups by default
              grouping: ["Name"], //an array of columns to group by by default (can be multiple)
              pagination: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 20 },
              sorting: [{ id: "Name", desc: false }], //sort by state by default
            }} />
```

I tried adding this. If I change "main" to something like #fff it will change! but as soon as I change to a custom rgb color then it gets over ridden.

```
 const muiTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      info: {
        main: 'rgb(0,64,255)'
        // rgb(6, 119, 209) symetra colors
      },
    },
    overrides :{
      MuiPaper: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,64,255,0.1)'
        }
      }
    }
  })
```